# Mini Display Port and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-optimus, displayport

Did someone manage to use the mini display port instead of the hdmi port of a laptop (with ubuntu 14.04) ? I use bumblebee and my laptop has a nvidia card. I already posted a remark in this thread [Dell XPS15 L502x Mini Display Port not working Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/408613/40581) and i am wondering if someone could have new information since then.

Comment: Please avoid using link shorteners.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your question is only for nvidia hardware, but I have an Intel Nuc (which containts basically laptop hardware) with the Intel HD 5000 GPU that has a mini display port, and this works perfectly using ubuntu 14.04.