# Ubuntu 14.04 Intel Graphics Dual / Extended Monitors

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Once Ubuntu user returned after a few years messing around with other distros. I have just installed 14.04 and I'm having an issue with my dual monitors. I've Googled this issue only to find solutions for setups with dedicated graphics (Nvidia/ATI) cards.

My laptop is using integrated Intel graphics. I have two monitors attached to my docking station, but Display is not detecting the seperate screens, and they are just being mirrored.

I have tried it with DVI x 2 and DVI + VGA, with no joy. It works fine on Windows.

Any ideas? I'd like to run an extended desktop over dual monitors (as one does).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768       60.1 +   40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   3840x1200      60.0  
   2560x1024      60.0  
   1920x1080      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: What is the output of running the `xrandr` command in a terminal?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/757081/119644 this helped for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your connection to the external monitors is through a *DisplayPort* connection to the docking device. The dock is using a single *DisplayPort* connection to provide both monitors over a single channel. To do this, it is using *Multi-Stream Transport* (MST), which is not yet well supported in Linux and Xorg.

Until the *Hardware Enablement Stack* for 14.04 becomes available after 14.10 is released, you won't be able to use the feature with the standard kernel and Xorg packages.

Options until a kernel and Xorg are available via normal channels on 14.04 that include this support, are to use a PPA which contains the back-ports of the necessary versions (assuming that the hardware you have is supported in the newer versions already), or compile your own packages.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've tried switching out the DisplayPort - DVI adaptor for VGA, using DVI and VGA, and the problem persists. But am I missing something here?

Comment: All the video ports on the dock appear as a single DisplayPort to the laptop. It is the _eDP1_ in the xrandr output.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. And advice re PPA?

Comment: Do older versions of Ubuntu support MST?

Comment: No, it's a relatively new technology and only recently has started to get real support in the upstream kernel and Xorg code bases. As far as PPAs, I don't know if there's a good one that has both the kernel and Xorg (or that it will even actually work with your hardware). There's a similar problem for 4K monitors, and I'm just using HDMI on mine for now.